# Apache NIFI Can't find or load main class on Debian when creating a user

Tags: java, debian, apache-nifi, java-11

I have to setup NIFI for a school project and when i have to use this command
`nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials myusername mypassword` (with proper password and username)
i always get this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.command.SetSingleUserCredentials
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.command.SetSingleUserCredentials
```

I installed jdk-11 and i'm working on Debian i don't really know what to do i tried to change jdk version but my school indicate that 11 is the good one and i never really worked with java before

My java is in the path i get this

```
java --version 

openjdk 11.0.0.1 2023-05-09
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.0.1+3-5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.0.1+3-5, mixed mode)
```